# JWT Token is expired or not?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, token, access-token

How to check whether the current JWT Token is expired or not in .NET Core application.

```
string token = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
```

I got the token value using above code. Similar i need a way to find the token is expired or not.

Comment: if you decode the JWT, there's usually an `exp` claim with the unix timestamp of when it's valid to.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the token expire time using this:

```
string accessTokenExpire = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("expires_at");
```

Alternatively, you as a client don't care about the expire time and instead renew the access token when the access token is rejected by the API receiving it.

Important, you are in the client, not supposed to look inside the access token.

Comment: Feel free to accept the my answer if the answer is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

We can find JWT token expired or not using below code.

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
var expiresAt = DateTimeOffset.Parse(await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("expires_at"));
if (expiresAt != null && expiresAt < DateTime.UtcNow)
{
   //Token Expired
}
```